# How to check a database connection is viable in Python, independently of the db type?

Tags: python, database-connection

My scenario: I am spinning up a docker network through Docker Compose to use as a testing environment using pytest.
I am spinning up two different types of databases (mysql and mongo) and various APIs interfacing to such databases.

In the compose file, I use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) on the APIs to wait for the databases to become available and this has worked fine for me.

In my pytest setup, I have created a fixture which runs before each test to make sure both the databases and the APIs are still up and healthy. While I can easily try to hit the /health endpoint of my API to see how they are doing, I am struggling to find a way to do so realiably for my databases.

I could retry the connection through their respective connectors with some backoff and catch the exceptions, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to use the specific mysql and mongo connectors. I would like to have a function which is agnostic to the type of database it is trying to connect to. I tried using socket, but I think this is not working. I probably don't really understand what is really going on when using socket.

Here's my current solution, which always tells the databases are up, when in fact they are not; I took this suggestion from a post on SOF which I can't track down now:

```
def ping_db(servername: str, server: str, port: int, timeout=3, retries=5, sleep=10):
"""ping server"""
logging.info(
    f"Checking if {servername} is up and ready to receive connections...")
for retry in range(0, retries):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((server, port))
    except socket.error as error:
        logging.warning(f"Failed connection attempt #{retry+1} to {servername} at address {server}:{port}; got exception: {error}; sleeping for "
                        f"{sleep} seconds before reattempt.")
        time.sleep(sleep)
    else:
        s.close()
        logging.info(f"{servername} at address {server}:{port} is available for connection after {retry + 1} tries.")
        return
```

Comment: The response you are getting is because, else is always getting executed.
I would suggest trying with broadening the except block with 'except BaseException' and get rid of 'else' to see whats the behavior and build from there.

Comment: Thank you @AshishSamarth. I shall try and report back.